# Haar measure on a Global Field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, haar-measure

Let $\Bbbk$ be a finite-degree field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. I am trying to figure out the formula  for the unique Haar measure $d\mu_{\Bbbk}$ on $\Bbbk$ normalized so that: $$\int_{\Bbbk}\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{O}_{\Bbbk}}\left(x\right)d\mu_{\Bbbk}\left(x\right)=1$$ where $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbbk}$ is the ring of $\Bbbk$-integers and $\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{O}_{\Bbbk}}\left(x\right)$ is the indicator function for $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbbk}$.

Since $\Bbbk$ is countable, I'm pretty sure this means that there is some function $f:\Bbbk\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ so that: $$\mu_{\Bbbk}\left(A\right)=\sum_{a\in A}f\left(a\right),\textrm{ }\forall A\subseteq\Bbbk$$ and hence, integration over $\Bbbk$ is really just summation (*à la* the counting measure). If so, what is the $f$? If not, what is the formula for $\mu_{\Bbbk}\left(A\right)$ for a given $A\subseteq\Bbbk$? I'm interested primarily because I want to try integrating specific functions over $\Bbbk$.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean. Do you mean that you are working with a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$? Unless you are giving $\mathbb{Q}$ the discrete topology then it's not locally compact, and thus the notion of Haar measure doesn't make sense. The point being that global fields don't have Haar measures. This is the entire point of working not with something like $\mathbb{Q}$ but its adele ring $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, I meant a number field, not a local field. I realized that the lack of local compactness on a number field means that its "haar measure" has to be the counting measure, or a variant thereof described by the summation-of-an-$f$ procedure I mentioned in my post. I guess you could say this question answered itself. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: This paper of K. Conrad (<https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/characterQ.pdf>) explains how to construct the group of characters on the rationals, and states that this method can be generalized to apply to any number field. I found this very helpful.